# Scipy Basinhopping: setting an array element with a sequence (approx_fprime)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

**Edit -- solved issue**

I was converting this code over from a least squares fit and thought I had changed all the return values in `do_fit` from arrays (as required by `scipy.optimize.leastsq`) to scalars (as required by `scipy.optimize.basinhopping`).

However, I forgot to change a line at the beginning of `calc_res` that checks if the trial parameters passed to it from `basinhopping` are out of bounds. If they are, it returns a huge residual *array*. After converting this to a huge residual *scalar* my code works fine, since a scalar is return whether or not the parameters are in or out of bounds.

**Original Post**

I'm having some trouble with the `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` algorithm, which is giving me an error from deep in the bowels of the `optimize.py` file,specifically in `approx_fprime`. I have confirmed that my objective function ("calc_res") is indeed returning a scalar as required (in my case, the sum of the squared residuals), but I still get a `setting an array element with a sequence` error.

I'm calling the basinhopping algorithm via the following code:

```py
def do_fit(vp,fp,vp_ids,fp_ids,exp_data):
#vp = variable params, fp = fixed params
#vp_ids, fp_ids are lists of ints (id #'s) which keep track
#  of which params are variable/fixed
minimizer_kwargs= {"method":"L-BFGS-B",
                     "args":(fp,vp_ids,fp_ids,exp_data)}
anneal_T = 100e-3
stepsize = 100e-3

f = opt.basinhopping(calc_res, vp,
                            niter=100,
                            T=anneal_T,
                            stepsize=stepsize,
                            minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
                            accept_test=None,
                            disp=True)

return f
```

The residual calculation in the function to minimize looks like

```py
def calc_res(vp,fp,vp_ids,fp_ids,exp_data):
    ########
    ######## Fit calculations removed for clarity
    ########

    res = data - fit
    res_sum = np.sum(res**2)

    #to confirm scalar is being return (type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>)
    ty = type(res_sum) 
    print('type = ',ty);sys.stdout.flush() 

    return res_sum
```

It calculates the first few values fine (and I can see the result is a scalar), but then I get this error code

```
In [7]: %run 04_gs_and_ir_annealing.py
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
type =  <class 'numpy.float64'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
     98         loc = loc if (loc is not None) else glob
     99         with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
--> 100             exec(compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec'), glob, loc)
    101 
    102     # Refactor print statements in doctests.

/home/xx/nmr/analysis/cowbrain/4pool_cpmg_gs_ir/04_gs_and_ir_annealing.py in <module>()
    477 
    478 res = calc_res(vp,fp,vp_ids,fp_ids,exp_data)
--> 479 fit_coeffs = do_fit(vp,fp,vp_ids,fp_ids,exp_data)
    480 print_params(fit_coeffs,vp_ids,fp_ids,nparam)
    481 plt.show(block=False)

/home/xx/nmr/analysis/cowbrain/4pool_cpmg_gs_ir/04_gs_and_ir_annealing.py in do_fit(vp, fp, vp_ids, fp_ids, exp_data)
    305                                 minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
    306                                 accept_test=None,
--> 307                                 disp=True) 
    308 
    309     return f

/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_basinhopping.py in basinhopping(func, x0, niter, T, stepsize, minimizer_kwargs, take_step, accept_test, callback, interval, disp, niter_success)
    567 
    568     bh = BasinHoppingRunner(x0, wrapped_minimizer, take_step_wrapped,
--> 569                             accept_tests, disp=disp)
    570 
    571     #start main iteration loop

/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_basinhopping.py in __init__(self, x0, minimizer, step_taking, accept_tests, disp)
     45 
     46         #do initial minimization
---> 47         minres = minimizer(self.x)
     48         self.x = np.copy(minres.x)
     49         self.energy = minres.fun

/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_basinhopping.py in __call__(self, x0)
    241             return self.minimizer(x0, **self.kwargs)
    242         else:
--> 243             return self.minimizer(self.func, x0, **self.kwargs)
    244 
    245 

/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    354     elif meth == 'l-bfgs-b':
    355         return _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
--> 356                                 callback=callback, **options)
    357     elif meth == 'tnc':
    358         return _minimize_tnc(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, callback=callback,

/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, **unknown_options)
    310                 n_function_evals += 1
    311                 # Overwrite f and g:
--> 312                 f, g = func_and_grad(x)
    313         elif task_str.startswith(b'NEW_X'):
    314             # new iteration

/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in func_and_grad(x)
    256         def func_and_grad(x):
    257             f = fun(x, *args)
--> 258             g = approx_fprime(x, fun, epsilon, *args)
    259             return f, g
    260     else:

/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in approx_fprime(xk, f, epsilon, *args)
    586         ei[k] = 1.0
    587         d = epsilon * ei
--> 588         grad[k] = (f(*((xk+d,)+args)) - f0) / d[k]
    589         ei[k] = 0.0
    590 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the error for scipy.optimize.minimize() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844347/understanding-the-error-for-scipy-optimize-minimize-function)