# Python: numpy and scipy minimize: setting an array element with a sequence minimize

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to minimize the function, but get an

> **ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**

in the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize as opt

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x / 5.) * np.exp(x / 10.) + 5 * np.exp( -x / 2.)

aprox_0 = np.array([range(1, 10), range(11, 20), range(21, 30)])
min_0 = opt.minimize(f, aprox_0[0])
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to happen if you feed an array as initial guess? The code works if you replace `aprox_0[0]` with a single value. Maybe you are just mistaken about the shape of aprox_0? It's a 2D array.

Comment: This question has a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844347/understanding-the-error-for-scipy-optimize-minimize-function

Comment: Thanks guys, I've found the issue: I thought about the finding local minimum via arrays and using them as a parameter instead of boundaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the dimensions of both x inside the function `f()` and its returning value during the mininization, when you find the problem probably the function [flatten()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) will help.